# TensorFlow/Keras: How to resume training using model.checkpoint()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm saving my best model using `model.checkpoint()`:

```
checkpoint = '/gdrive/MyDrive/mpmodel.ckpt'
cdir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint)

cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_path, 
    verbose=1, 
    save_weights_only=False,
    save_best_only=True)

history = model.fit([timt,at],[wt,wbt],epochs=100,callbacks=[cp_callback])
```

This is how I'm loading my model:

```
latest = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(cdir)
model.load(latest)
```

Now, I want to resume training from where I last left off. In [this ipynb](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/keras/save_and_load.ipynb#scrollTo=1AN_fnuyR41H), it's mentioned:

> Since the optimizer-state is recovered, you can resume training from
> exactly where you left off.

However, it doesn't exactly tell me how to do that. Please guide me.

Comment: Is there any solution in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

After model.load(latest), you could continue using model.fit()

Anyway, using checkpoint callback is not common I think. It is more common to use model.save(MODEL_NAME) and then reload the model using model= tf.keras.models.load_model(MODEL_NAME)

MODEL_NAME is the folder where you saved your model.

Comment: model.fit() restarts the training from the first epoch , I want it to restart from the epoch when my runtime got disconnected. Also, I didn't use model.save() because it doesn't support callbacks , so it won't be able to save the model at the end of each epoch. It can only be used after the training has been completed.

Comment: @KenAdams you could add initial_epoch to the model.fit() arguments. AFAIK, the model.load_model() still loads all the previous state (at least the weight). If you use the model.fit() again, yes the epoch will start at zero. But it will start using the newest weight state.

Comment: The checkpoint callback is useful when the training could be interrupted (e.g. where I train, I have to select a certain number of hours my server works beforehand and if training takes longer, I won't reach model.save), so I'd be interested in resuming from callback...